# Databricks incorrect data while writing in Delta location

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks, spark-notebook, azure-notebooks

I am facing below issue while writing the data in Delta location. I am getting incorrect data. I am using Python Notebook in Azure Databricks.
Dataset Used : /databricks-datasets/flights/

Below are the steps I performed.

#### Mount to blob storage.

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://flight@storageaccount7830.blob.core.windows.net",
    mount_point = "/mnt/blobstorage",
    extra_configs = {'fs.azure.account.key.storageaccount7830.blob.core.windows.net':'accountKey'}
)
```

### Save it in the Delta Table

```
fulldf = spark.read.format("csv").option("header",True).option("inferSchema",True).load('/databricks-datasets/flights/')
 
fulldf.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/blobstorage/Full")
```

### Select the data to limit 10

```
df=fulldf.limit(10)
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/blobstorage/Small")
```

### Display the data. I am getting the output like this.

```
%sql
select * from delta.`/mnt/blobstorage/Small`
```

[image]

### Output should be like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the right thing is for you to use a schema instead of making the inference, and another thing seems to me that the CSV files in the load directory are positional, so you would need to pass the option like this

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("date",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("delay",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("distance",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("origin", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("destination", StringType(), True), \
  ])

fulldf = spark\
        .read\
        .format("csv")\
        .option("delimiter","\t")\
        .option("header",false)\
        .schema(schema)\
        .option("path","/databricks-datasets/flights/")\
        .load()

df.limit(10).write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/blobstorage/Small")
```

Comment: Hi @chá de boldo,